# Why is the GETDATE() an invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, function, triggers

Why is the GETDATE() an invalid identifier says Oracle Sql Developer tool when I debug this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SPName
AFTER UPDATE
ON TableName 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableName SET LastModifiedDate = GETDATE() WHERE TableName.DET_ID = :new.DET_ID;
END;
```

Comment: 1) Use `sysdate` instead of `getdate()`.  2) You are not allowed to access table inside trigger defined for this table.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you want `SYSDATE`, not `GETDATE()`. Try it:

```
UPDATE TableName SET LastModifiedDate = (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use ORACLE equivalent of `getdate()` which is `sysdate` . [Read about here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)
Getdate() belongs to SQL Server , will not work on Oracle.

Other option is `current_date`

Comment: What about current_date? Is the same?

Answer (score 3):

`getdate()` for MS-SQL, `sysdate` for Oracle server

Comment: So; how does this add to the two answers which already covered this information?

Answer (score 1):

`SYSDATE` and `GETDATE` perform identically.

`SYSDATE` is compatible with Oracle syntax, and `GETDATE` is compatible with Microsoft SQL Server syntax.