# dateadd and between in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that prompts for a startdate and enddate,  Between @startdate And @enddate.  But what I am trying to do is have the same query automatically look 3 months forward from today's month using a dateadd / getdate code, but can not figure out how to integrate the two?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Our company has a tool that is web based, looks like Access, and builds the SQL and validates at the bottom.  Here is a sample where I am talking: ***Where vwS_CoPrimPolicy.S_PrimPolicyExpDT Between "at"startdate And "at"enddate And vwS_Co.S_CoStatus = 'Customer' And vwS_Co.S_CoType = 'Automotive'***  The query talks with our Siebel DB.  So the output is a list of records pulled in July for all of October, so 10/1/16 - 10/31/16.  This will be ran every month, always looking 90 days ahead.

Answer (score 0):

In sql-server, which I assume because you are referencing `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD()`

```
DATEADD(MONTH,3,GETDATE())
```

IN Oracle based on [Why is the GETDATE() an invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972188/why-is-the-getdate-an-invalid-identifier), and [Equivalent function for DATEADD() in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle)

```
ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3)
```

Based on your comment and if Siebel is on sql-server you would need

```
Where vwS_CoPrimPolicy.S_PrimPolicyExpDT Between @startdate And @enddate And vwS_Co.S_CoStatus = 'Customer' And vwS_Co.S_CoType = 'Automotive
```

to become

```
where vwS_CoPrimPolicy.S_PrimPolicyExpDT Between 

DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,3,GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,3,GETDATE())),1)
    AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,4,GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,4,GETDATE())),1))

 And vwS_Co.S_CoStatus = 'Customer' And vwS_Co.S_CoType = 'Automotive
```

To Break that down a little because you are actually looking for the start of the month 3 months from today to the end of the month 3 months from today and those months could be 28,29,30,or 31 days long you actually need to find the date 3 months ahead then get the beginning of the month `DATEFROMPARTS()` is useful for that.  Then for the end of the month, find the date 4 months out and go back a day.