# How to subtract date from current date in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am writing some test cases and for that I need to subtract 7 days and 30 days from the current date. I am using getDate() function to get the current date. I am not exactly sure how to achieve this?

Below is my query and for the transaction id 14867 I need to update the date column to go back to 7 days and similarly I will write another query to subtract 30 days from the current date.

```
UPDATE ESG.DOC_TRAN
    SET DOCUMENT_TRANSACTION.CREATED_DATE = getDate()
    WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = 14867;
```

Thanks

Comment: [`GETDATE()` is not an Oracle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972188/why-is-the-getdate-an-invalid-identifier)

Comment: You can't be using Oracle if that SQL statement works for you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Ironically, the code wouldn't work in SQL Server either.

Comment: I can remove the tag ORACLE.

Comment: So which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product **are** you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Side note: one tenet of testing is _repeatability_.  The fact that you're updating a database is worrying: it implies this is a "permanent" (And possibly shared) database, and not something loaded as part of a test script (which presumably would be able to supply the current date).  Of course, getting the current date/time is one of the most insidious dependencies in any program, but unless you have something like [Java's `Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) it can be hard to remove.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty approach, you can simply use GetDate()-7 and GetDate()-30

e.g.

```
UPDATE ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION SET DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.CREATED_DT = getDate()-7 WHERE DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID = 14867;
```

Comment: `GETDATE` is not an Oracle function.

Comment: Perhaps this is mistagged then, as the code is from the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the following query to get what you wanted!

```
SELECT sysdate, sysdate-7 FROM DUAL;
```

The query above will print you both the current date and also the date 7 days behind today, same day last week. With this, you can add whatever logic that you want as well! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate-7` will give you the date for last week.